# How can i get genres and descriptions of movies in IMBd API?

Tags: api, google-sheets, imdb

so Im using the Top 250 Movies database in IMDb's API and i need the genres and descriptions of all the movies but i looked in [IMDb's API](https://imdb-api.com/api) list and they don't have anything about genres or descriptions.

I just want the genres and the short description on the [IMDb website](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/?pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&pf_rd_p=1a264172-ae11-42e4-8ef7-7fed1973bb8f&pf_rd_r=964NEWNVTPQ8BWQADV34&pf_rd_s=center-1&pf_rd_t=15506&pf_rd_i=top&ref_=chttp_tt_2) when you are on a movie.

And if anyones want to know i exporting the data into a spreadsheet. google sheets to be specific.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following **IMPORTXML**:

For **Plot** use :

```
=IMPORTXML("imdb movie url","//*[@data-testid='plot-xl']")
```

For **Genres** use :

```
=IMPORTXML("imdb movie url","//*[@data-testid='genres']")
```

**Example:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en)
- [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath)